# SQL pivot count and sum 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
shopid  times   times2
shop1   5        1
shop2   2        2
shop1   6        1
shop1   1        1
shop2   1        2
```

Query and I got count correct for column Times

```
Select  [shop1], [Shop2]
from 
(
  Select  shopid, times
  from table3 
)p
pivot 
(
  count(times)
  for shopid in ([shop1], [Shop2])
)pvt;
```

Results correct count3 for shop1, count 2 for shop2

```
shop1   Shop2
  3      2
```

new query add column times2

```
Select  [shop1], [Shop2]
from 
(
  Select  shopid, times, times2
  from table3 
)p
pivot 
(
  count(times)
  for shopid in ([shop1], [Shop2])
)pvt;
```

Results and not count for column times2. Can we count and sum for both columns? Thank you.

```
shop1   Shop2
3        0
0        2
```

Expect results

```
shop1   Shop2
  6      4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is a UNION ALL

**Example**

```
Select  [shop1], [Shop2]
from 
(
  Select  shopid, times
  from  table3 
  Union All 
  Select shopid, times2
  from  table3 
)p
pivot 
(
  count(times)
  for shopid in ([shop1], [Shop2])
)pvt;
```

**Returns**

```
shop1   Shop2
6       4
```

And Yet another option is change the count to a SUM()

**Example**

```
Select  [shop1], [Shop2]
from 
(
  Select  shopid, times = IsNull(sign(Times),0)+IsNull(sign(Times2),0)
  from table3 
)p
pivot 
(
  sum(times)
  for shopid in ([shop1], [Shop2])
)pvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use cross tabs for this. No need for derived tables and just a simple copy-paste-replace to adapt as many ids as needed.

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN shopid = 'shop1' THEN SIGN(times)+SIGN(times2) ELSE 0 END) shop1,
       SUM( CASE WHEN shopid = 'shop2' THEN SIGN(times)+SIGN(times2) ELSE 0 END) shop2
FROM table3;
```